# Grep a string in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a log file that records string like this:  (1512424528.554:0:1880:1880).   I need to grep out only the lines where the last value is over 1000 and print them.  Thoughts?

Comment: Use `awk` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Grep is not the most pragmatic tool for this task. As @WilliamPursell adviced use awk or other tools for this problem.

**Solutions**:

Using **grep**: You can solve it but not perfectly by looking for at least 4 digits starting with a digit 1 to 9 (`[1-9][0-9]{3,}`) between the last colon (`.*:` matching everything until the last colon) and the end of the line (`$`) using perl-regexp (`-P` flag). This solution is not perfect since it gives you result for greater than or equal to 1000.

```
grep -P '.*:[1-9][0-9]{3,}$' your_file
```

Using **awk**: You can simply compare the last field (`$NF`) to 1000 after setting the field delimiter with `-F`.

```
awk -F':' '$NF > 1000 { print $0 }' your_file
```

Using **perl**: You can lookup for the last digits between the last colon and the end of the line and capture those digits `(\d+)` into `$1` that is compared to 1000.

```
perl -ne 'print if (/.*:(\d+)$/ and  $1>1000)' your_file
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments of @vaettchen I added solutions to take into account the parenthesis if they are part of the logged strings.

**grep**:

```
grep -P '.*:[1-9][0-9]{3,}\)$' your_file
```

**awk**:

```
awk -F':' 'substr($NF, 0, length($NF)-1)*1 > 1000' your_file
```

**perl**:

```
perl -ne 'print if (/.*:(\d+)\)$/ and  $1>1000)' your_file
```

Comment: The OP did not say clearly whether the parenthesis are part of the string or not. If they are, none of the above solutions would work. And for `awk` no need for the statement, simply `awk -F':' '$NF > 1000 ' your_file` would do